# Let $p(x)$ be a real polynomial such that for all $x$, we have $p(x)+p'(x)\ge 0$. Prove that for all $x,p(x)\ge 0$.

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, contest-math

Let $p(x)$ be a real polynomial such that for all $x$, we have $p(x)+p'(x)\ge 0$. Prove that for all $x,p(x)\ge 0$.

Take $p(x)=a_nx^n+\dots+a_1x+a_0$ and $p'(x)=na_nx^{n-1}+\dots+2a_2x+a_1$. So $$g(x)=p(x)+p'(x)=a_nx^n+(na_n+a_{n-1})x^{n-1}+\dots+(2a_2+a_1)x+(a_1+a_0)$$

Then note that $g(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$. And now we look at the graph of this polynomial. But I couldn't go much far. Another thing I wanted to say was that for negative enough $x$, we can have $p(x)$ to be negative, unless degree of $p(x)$ is even.